# Center and hide image, fitting div size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to center a image of width `1400px` inside a width `960px` div, and hide 220px for left and 220px for right.

[image]

```
<div style="width:960px;">
    <img src="src" style="width:1400px" />
</div>
```

Comment: OPS, not figured. It was mistyped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple with the following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
    height: 400px;
}
#wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -220px;
    width: 1400px;
}
```

If you don't know the height, you would probably want to use either a negative left margin, or position: relative.

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
}
#wrapper img {
    position: relative;
    left: -220px;
    display: block;
}
```

If the size of your image is dynamic, you could try something like this:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper .inner {
    width: 10000px;
    position: relative;
    left: -4520px; /* 5000 minus half the wrapper width */

}
#wrapper .inner img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note that this requires an extra wrapper, `.inner`.

Comment: I believe the #wrapper will need a height once the img is set to absolute. Also the top:0 wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: And, if the width/height to hid is dynamic? Solution?

Comment: Added an example to the original post for this scenario.

Comment: It did not work completely, but now I understand the logic. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!  I didn't test this code, so sorry if there are some bugs in it.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
div {overflow:hidden;}
img {margin-left: -220px;}
```